# Set max-routes from network-manager-openvpn

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

The openvpn of my company is pushing about 250 routes. I can connect by the command line interface of openvpn by using `max-routes 300` in the clients config file. By importing this file into nm, this setting is ignored and the connection fails due to too many routes. There is already a bug report [upstream](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720097), nevertheless, I'm searching for a *workaround* for the few colleagues running linux. All of them run ubuntu, therefore a ubuntu-specific workaround would help.

To give some starting point, what I searched for and google was not answering is the possibility of a global configuration of openvpn options to set `max-routes` or the ability to give nm additional options that don't show up in the gui.

**Solved:** The upstream problem was solved about 1 year ago. Unfortunately too late for me since I left the company, and there's no other linux machine left, they are purely running Windows and Apple now.

Comment: I'm facing this problem too, for a _workaround_, do not use network-manager-openvpn.

Comment: @favadi: That's what I actually do, I use the openvpn CLI. Nevertheless, I still hope for a possibility to overwrite the max-routes setting somewhere in the nm to be able to use the GUI. The GUI has several benefits, e. g. it is possible to configure if the internet traffic is routet over vpn or not, which I have to do manually with the CLI (of course I could write a script, but at least I have to entirely understand the complex routing that is introduced by the openvpn connection, more than 250 routes in total, in the GUI it's just one click), and it makes my desktop less cluttered.

Comment: @favadi: ... (not enough space in one comment) Additionally, several colleagues just don't want to use the CLI (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the connection settings, click on `Advanced`. At the end of the `General` tab, should be the setting for `Specify max routes`.

Network Manager 1.2.6 and `network-manager-openvpn 1.2.6-2ubuntu1` here.

Comment: The necessary functionality seems to have been added during the last 3 years. Unfortunately I cannot test since I have no access to this network any more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing with such problem too.
Openvpn can be started with option --max-routes xxx, where xxx - number of routes. So, I rename file /usr/sbin/openvpn to /usr/sbin/openvpnm (modified). Then create new file /usr/sbin/openvpn with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/openvpnm --max-routes 500 "$@"
```

Where 500 is number of the routes.

Make this file executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

Now Network manager works with fine.